# How can I add a file extension using TKinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pickle

I am trying to save a pickle dump to a .pkl file using Tkinter. I followed the documentation but when I save the file it has no extension. This is a snippet:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
messagebox.showinfo("Select Save Location", "Please save the Feature list")
Tk().withdraw()
savedf = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("Pickle Dumps","*.pkl")])
```

How do I make it so that if I name the file hello it will save as hello.pkl when the user only specifies the file name?

Comment: You probably have to type the filename *including the extension* into the "ask filename" dialog.

Comment: Oh I wanted to make it so the user only has to specify the file name not the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `defaultextension` parameter:

```
filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.pkl')
```

Comment: Except on MacOsx, `defaultextension=''` causes the first extension of the current filetype to be copied.  This is useful when one has multiple file types, as with IDLE save-as ((.py, .pyw), .txt).