# Saving tkinter canvas with Pillow saves extensionless file but won't specify extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I've been working on a personal project that is supposed to generate several squares in different colors, then open a save dialog box, let the user pick the name for the file, and save the image when the user clicks the save button.

So far everything is working except the save function. The save dialog works. I am able to get my code to save a file, but it never saves it as a PNG. In fact, it doesn't save with any extension at all, but if I don't specify format="PNG" then it won't even save a file and just throws a ValueError:
ValueError('unknown file extension: {}'.format(ext))
ValueError: unknown file extension: .

For simplicity here's all the relevant bits of my code in question. What could I be doing wrong?

(For reference's sake I'm a super beginner. I just finished an intro to Python course and I'm trying to branch into some more advanced things. I've searched and searched for a solution for this but I'm at a loss. Also I realize if I import all from PIL/tkinter then I shouldn't have to specify specific things, but I get different errors if I'm not specific. It's my limited understanding that this is some sort of a known bug or something?)

edit: forgot to mention that when I do save an extensionless file, if I manually rename it from, for example, 'test' to 'test.png', the image shows up correctly. In other words I can see my code is saving the correct data but it's just not adding the .png to the filename for some reason.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageGrab, PngImagePlugin
from PIL import *

class MyFrame(Frame):
      def __init__(self):
         Frame.__init__(self)
         self.grid()

         self.myCanvas = Canvas(self, width=400, height=175)
         self.myCanvas.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 5)

         self.myCanvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50, fill="blue")

         self.button_saveImage = Button(self, text = "Save", command = self.save_image)
         self.button_saveImage.grid(row = 4, column = 4, padx = 5, pady=15)

      def save_image(self):
         x=self.winfo_rootx()+self.myCanvas.winfo_x()
         y=self.winfo_rooty()+self.myCanvas.winfo_y()
         x1=x+self.myCanvas.winfo_width()
         y1=y+self.myCanvas.winfo_height()

         filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "C:/Users/desktop.ini",
                                                  title = "Select file",
                                                  filetypes = (("PNG files","*.png"),("All files","*.*")))
         ImageGrab.grab().crop((x,y,x1,y1)).save(filename, format="PNG")

frame01 = MyFrame()
frame01.mainloop()
mainloop()
```

Comment: did you check what you have in `filename` after `asksaveasfilename` ? If you have name without extension then `save()` will save it without extension. It doesn't add `extension` and it doesn't use extension to recognize in what format save it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a file extension using TKinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517738/how-can-i-add-a-file-extension-using-tkinter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try configuring `defaultextension=".png"` for `filedialog.asksaveasfilename` method.

As in:

```
filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "C:/Users/desktop.ini",
                                                  title = "Select file",
                                                  filetypes = (("PNG files","*.png"),("All files","*.*")))
```

needs to be:

```
filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "C:/Users/desktop.ini",
                                                  title = "Select file",
                                                  filetypes = (("PNG files","*.png"),("All files","*.*"))
                                                  defaultextension=".png")
```